# GPUImageMaskFilter Background Color

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I am having problems setting the background colour using the GPUImageMaskFilter. It seems to be that the first time i press the button to run the script the output is of a white colour. On the second press the correct black colour is returned as a background colour.

```
UIImage *imgMask = [self createMaskImage:maskImage canvasImage:sourceImage maskWidth:200 maskHeight:200];
UIImage *imgBgImage = sourceImage;


GPUImagePicture * maskGpuImage = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:imgMask ];
GPUImagePicture *FullGpuImage = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:imgBgImage];

GPUImageMaskFilter *maskingFilter = [[GPUImageMaskFilter alloc] init];
[maskingFilter setBackgroundColorRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];

// Image first, Mask next
[FullGpuImage addTarget:maskingFilter];
[FullGpuImage processImage];

[maskingFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];

[maskGpuImage addTarget:maskingFilter];
[maskGpuImage processImage];

return [maskingFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
```